# how to add dot after three digits in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new angular js . I want to make input pattern XXX.XXXX .If user enter float value then it should not do anything but if user enter 1234456 (non decimal value)  then it will automatically make 123.4560 
if user enter 12.909 then it does not do anything . After third non decimal digit it should add dot. Kindly help

Comment: Start by looking at directives. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive Then post something you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following it will help :

**JS**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onBlur = function($event) {

     var num = $scope.foo;

      if (num.indexOf(".") == -1 && num.length > 4)
      {
        $scope.foo = num.substring(0,3) + "." + num.substring(3);
      }    
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-blur="onBlur($event)"/>
</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/25399/)

Comment: this will not work if have for example 1million

Comment: it only asks to place a dot after 3 places, nothing more than that, it works for any integer, read question carefully and use fiddle created for it

Answer (score 0):

You would have a function that run on keypress or watches the binded value.
Check if the string is a number and then use toFixed minus 3 of the length of the string, something like this (not tested):

```
if (str.isNaN()) {
    return "";
} else {
    var length = (str.length - 3); 
    return str.toFixed(length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using a simple function on blur event of the input box.

```
$scope.inputValue = "";
  $scope.checkDecimal  = function()
  {
    if(!isNaN($scope.inputValue) && $scope.inputValue % 1 !== 0)
    {
      alert("Its a decimal value");
    }
    else if(!isNaN($scope.inputValue) && $scope.inputValue.length > 3)
    {
      var deNominator = Math.pow(10, ($scope.inputValue.length - 3) );
      $scope.inputValue = $scope.inputValue /deNominator;
    }
    else if(!isNaN($scope.inputValue) && $scope.inputValue < 1000)
    {
       $scope.inputValue =  $scope.inputValue;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Please enter a valid number value");
      $scope.inputValue = "";
    }
  }
```

Plunker for reference : http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview